# Python Smtp SSL wrong version on linux

Tags: python, ssl, smtp

My code to send emails via msft outlook.com works on windows but not on my linux box. Any idea how to fix this?

```
import smtplib
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com', port=587)
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login(username, password)

SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: 
[Errno 1] _ssl.c:1359: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

EDIT: more details: gentoo linux with python 2.7.3, openssl 0.9.8x and 1.0.1c

Comment: What is your ```python -V``` and ```openssl version```?

Comment: @korylprince python 2.7.3, openssl 0.9.8x

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to upgrade your openssl. Your code works fine for me.

Comment: @korylprince what's your openssl version?

Comment: ```OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012``` on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I actually have both openssl 1.0.1 and 0.9.8 installed, don't think its the version

Comment: Works fine for me too (Python 2.7.3, openssl 1.0.1c).

Comment: Why do you have openssl:0.9.8 installed? Does any package depend on it  it?

Comment: Which version of `openssl` does you Python use? (`ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`)

Comment: @kirelagin my python is on OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012

Comment: Ok, you should have mentioned that this error appears _only after successful authentication_ … Now I see it too.

Comment: That's totally weird. I managed to succesfully login a number of times, but that seems to be kinda random…

Comment: @kefeizhou I'm having this problem too. Did you file a bug with the Gentoo maintainers?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17434143

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hotmail SSL3 version number error using smtp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434143/hotmail-ssl3-version-number-error-using-smtp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet the problem is on the other side of the wire. Hello, Microsoft!

I've tried logging in a number of times, and you won't believe me, but some servers will let me in, while others won't.
Try doing `smtp.ehlo()` in order to find the server's hostname (by the way, you *must* issue `EHLO` at the beginning of your session, and immediately after `STARTTLS`).

All their servers have names `BLU0-SMTP<somenumber>phx.gbl`. Believe me or not, but servers with *two* digits in their name are OK, but those with *three* digits are not.

```
In [52]: s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com', port=587)

In [53]: s.ehlo()
Out[53]:
(250,
 'BLU0-SMTP17.phx.gbl Hello [188.134.8.114]\nTURN\nSIZE 41943040\nETRN\nPIPELINING\nDSN\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\n8bitmime\nBINARYMIME\nCHUNKING\nVRFY\nTLS\nSTARTTLS\nOK')

In [54]: s.starttls()
Out[54]: (220, '2.0.0 SMTP server ready')

In [55]: s.ehlo()
Out[55]:
(250,
 'BLU0-SMTP17.phx.gbl Hello [188.134.8.114]\nTURN\nSIZE 41943040\nETRN\nPIPELINING\nDSN\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\n8bitmime\nBINARYMIME\nCHUNKING\nVRFY\nAUTH LOGIN PLAIN\nOK')

In [56]: s.login(login, password)
Out[56]: (235, '2.7.0 Authentication succeeded')
```

```
In [42]: s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com', port=587)

In [43]: s.ehlo()
Out[43]:
(250,
 'BLU0-SMTP116.phx.gbl Hello [188.134.8.114]\nTURN\nSIZE 41943040\nETRN\nPIPELINING\nDSN\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\n8bitmime\nBINARYMIME\nCHUNKING\nVRFY\nTLS\nSTARTTLS\nOK')

In [44]: s.starttls()
Out[44]: (220, '2.0.0 SMTP server ready')

In [45]: s.ehlo()
Out[45]:
(250,
 'BLU0-SMTP116.phx.gbl Hello [188.134.8.114]\nTURN\nSIZE 41943040\nETRN\nPIPELINING\nDSN\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\n8bitmime\nBINARYMIME\nCHUNKING\nVRFY\nAUTH LOGIN PLAIN\nOK')

In [46]: s.login(login, password)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SMTPServerDisconnected                    Traceback (most recent call last)
```

---

Update: Hm, seems that it is a [known issue with 1.0.1c](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/error-1408F10B-SSL-routines-SSL3-GET-RECORD-wrong-version-number-td22477.html).

Comment: Yeah that's the problem. I downgraded to 1.0.0j and smtp works now.

Comment: @kefeizhou Why don't you upgrade to 1.0.1e instead?

Comment: @kirelagin, I am getting the same problem with 1.0.1e.