# How to fix ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)?

Tags: python, ssl, smtplib

I am trying to send an email with python, but it keeps saying `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)`. Here is my code:

```py
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.com', 587)
server.login("something0@mail.com", "password")
server.sendmail(
"something0@mail.com", 
"something@mail.com", 
"email text")
server.quit()
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: What's your *OS*, *Python* version, and *OpenSSL* version? Also if you open the command interpreter, what does `import ssl`, `print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)` output?

Comment: @CristiFati Windows 10 Home, 3.7, OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018

Comment: you are using the wrong port for SSL 
587 is for TLS
465 for SSL

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The port for `SSL` is 465 and not 587, however when I used `SSL` the mail arrived to the junk mail.

For me the thing that worked was to use `TLS` over regular `SMTP` instead of `SMTP_SSL`.

Note that this is a secure method as [`TLS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) is also a cryptographic protocol (like SSL).

```
import smtplib, ssl

port = 587  # For starttls
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = "my@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "your@gmail.com"
password = input("Type your password and press enter:")
message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

provided thanks to the [real python tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/).

Answer (score 3):

this is how i solved same problem

```
import ssl


sender = "youremail@yandex.ru"
password = "password123"
    
where_to_email = "reciever@anymail.com"
theme = "this is subject"
message = "this is your message, say hi to reciever"
    
sender_password = password
session = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.ru', 465)
session.login(sender, sender_password)
msg = f'From: {sender}\r\nTo: {where_to_email}\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"\r\nSubject: {theme}\r\n\r\n'
msg += message
session.sendmail(sender, where_to_email, msg.encode('utf8'))
session.quit()
```

also if you want to use `yandex` mail `you must` to turn on "protal code" in settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Code to send email via python:**

```
import smtplib , ssl
import getpass
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com",465)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls
password = getpass.getpass()   # to hide your password while typing (feels cool)
server.login("example@gmail.com", password)
server.sendmail("example@gmail.com" , "sender-example@gmail.com" , "I am trying out python email through coding")
server.quit()
```

#turn off LESS SECURE APPS to make this work on your gmail

Answer (score 0):

google no longer lets you turn this feature off, meaning it just wont work no matter what you do, yahoo appears to be the same way